# How to stop overiding a bean in Spring

Tags: spring

I noticed that if you define a bean with same id in two xml files, it would be overiden in the second file.

```
Say in file a.xml i have
       <bean id="abc" />

Say in file b.xml i have
       <bean id="abc" />
```

then the bean "abc" of b.xml is picked up. Is there a way in Spring to stop from overiding i.e should be unique no matter how many xml have the bean abc.

Comment: No. What should happen if 2 beans with the same name/id exists? What if you have dependencies to bean abc (first) and abc (second) how should spring know which one to use (if not using autowiring by type).

Comment: I was actually expecting an attribute something like override=false or final=true so that if the bean with the same id is used Spring will not allow it by throwing an exception.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the feature to disallow beanoverriding by calling the `setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding` and pass `false`. This has to be done early on before anything is loaded. You would either need to create your own custom `ContextLoader` for this or (if you are on Spring 3.1 or up) you can create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` and register this in your web.xml.

```
public class OverrideDisablingApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer {

    public void void initialize(<? extends ConfigurableApplicationContext> applicationContext);
        if (applicationContext instanceof AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext) {
             (AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext (applicationContext)).setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
        }

}
```

in your web.xml add the following (for the `ContextLoaderListener` use an init-param for the `DispatcherServlet` when needed)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>your.package.here.OverrideDisablingApplicationContextInitializer<param-value>
</context-param>
```

From the top of my head this should disable the overriding behavior. If you use springs WebApplicationInitializer it is even easier as you are probably constructing the `ApplicationContext` yourself, you can then simply call the method directly and no `ApplicationContextInitializer` is needed.

Links

1. ApplicationContextInitializer [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html)
2. AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.html#setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
  final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
  ctx.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
  ctx.setConfigLocations(shardContextImport);
  ctx.setParent(refreshedEvent.getApplicationContext());
  ctx.refresh();
```