# Can I use predefined by Spring Framework bean names for own purpose?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Can I use predefined by Spring Framework bean names for own purpose?

Like defining own bean with name that already in use? The problem that during development I am not aware of existing names and worry about possible collisions.

With empty Spring Boot application there are a lot of "generic" names allocated, like:

```
error
mvcValidator
viewResolver
counterService
serverProperties
```

You may check yourself with:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(App.class);
Arrays.stream(ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()).forEach(name -> System.out.println(name));
```

Comment: No not without consequences as that will override/replace other beans.

Comment: So it is possible accidentally clobber predefined bean name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a bean is created, and a bean with the same name already exists, the new bean will override the existing bean.

This is good, because it allows you to use your own beans to replace spring default beans, but it definitely allows to accidentally break the functionality of spring default beans.

This behavior can be changed by using

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory#setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding

If set to false, no override is allowed, instead an exception will be thrown. How this can be done is answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034273/how-to-stop-overiding-a-bean-in-spring)

If spring overrides an existing bean, you will see in the log something like

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'viewResolver' with a different definition:
```

So its something to be aware of, but in practice its not a big problem.