# Disable BeanDefinitionOverriding Spring Boot wep app ( war file)

Tags: java, spring-boot, web

if I have duplicate bean name Spring boot will override it. I want to disable this feature. I saw many discussions to this where it disables the overriding inside the main method. but in web app the main method will not be invoked at all. How can I disable it ?

Answer (score 1):

In your main method you need to create a new `ApplicationContextInitializer` and override its `initialize()` method for disabling the bean definition override. See below:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringBootApp.class)
    .initializers(new ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext>()
        {
            @Override
            public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext applicationContext)
            {
                applicationContext.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
            }
        })
    .run(args);
```

**--UPDATE--**

Since you deploy as web app, the above method will not work, of course.

You can implement the [WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) interface and override its `startup()` method, providing a custom `ApplicationContextInitializer`:

```
public class CustomInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>
{
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) 
    {
        applicationContext.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
    }
}

public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer 
{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
    {
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setContextInitializers(new CustomInitializer());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already said that the main method is not invoked at all this webapp not jar.

Comment: Didnt work, I got syntax error on :   applicationContext.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);

Comment: @Mohammad Karmi Yes, because you need an implementation of `ConfigurableApplicationContext` that provides this function (i.e., `AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19046795/4000124)

Comment: fixed the syntax error , but the overriding still not disabled